# Cant find modules 'fibers' in Meteor in Windows OS

Tags: node.js, fibers

I tried to use Future by using `var Future = require('fibers/future')`. I installed fibers using `meteor npm install --save fibers`, `meteor npm install fibers`, `npm install -g fibers`, `meteor npm install --save node-gyp, and`
npm install -g node-gyp`.

I used the future in imports folder, accessToken file. The file is imported in server folder file. In building app, there is no error. But when I am visiting homepage, I receive error of cannot find module 'fibers'.

Comment: Same issue when built with Meteor 1.8 on OSX 10.14.6 (both node v12 and node v8) and also on CentOS node v8